# Generic method and this

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create a generic save method which should be working like this;

```
Entity.User.User user = new Entity.User.User();
user.FirstName = "A";
user.LastName = "B";
user.UserName = "C";
user.Save();

public class User : BaseClass<User>
{
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    //I WANT THIS METHOD TO BE GENERIC UNDER BASE CLASS
    //public void Save() 
    //{
    //    CREATE.New(this);
    //}
}

public partial class BaseClass<T>
{
    public void Save(this T x)
    {
        CREATE<T>.New(x);
    }
}

public class CREATE<T>
{
    public static void New(T x)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

but I am getting error of "Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class"

looking for a guide to manage to this work. thank you

Comment: extension methods also can't be virtual; what is it that you are trying to do? if that is a base class, the `this` is just regular `this` - no need for a `this T x`; just `CREATE<T>.New(this)`. `CREATE<T>` is a terrible name, btw.

Comment: Sorry, but isn't this a circular reference? `public class User : BaseClass<User>`

Comment: I fixed the virtual. updated

Comment: The class CREATE should be static if you have a static method in it.

Comment: @Marc Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer

Comment: @stmnmn I presume you mean "if you *only* have a static method in it".

Comment: @Mert i didn't mention static; just: stop trying to create an extension method when a regular method is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your generic approach, I *think* what you are after is:

```
public partial class BaseClass<T>
{
    public virtual void Save()
    {
        // only support the T : BaseClass<T> scenario, so
        // we expect "this" to be a T
        CREATE<T>.New((T)(object)this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, and It worked. also I didnt lose generic funtionality looks like better solution. thank you, I am new on generics so It takes time to understand fully for me. thank you

Answer (score 3):

To Share a Save method with all your "entities" you neither need a Generic Parent class, nor do you need extension methods.

it's just a simple inheritance:

```
public class User : BaseClass
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public void Save()
    {
       //put save logic here. Should match for all 
       //concrete implementations of BaseClass
    }
}
```

now you simple can call

```
User user = new User();
user.FirstName = "A";
user.LastName = "B";
user.UserName = "C";
user.Save();
```

Generally you want to have each Class in your inheritance-Tree to save it's own attributes and then call parent's save(), so you dont have to repeat your self over and over.

The concrete implementation depens on how you are *saving*. If it's just a serialization, you could stick with one global save method on the BaseClass and childs do not need to provide any implementation on save().

---

i.e. to build a string, you could do something like this: So EACH Class just provides the part it is responsible for:

```
public class User : BaseClass
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override String Save(){
        s = base.Save(); //recall base.Save() as long as its not the topmost-entity
        //attach Username, password, firstname, lastname
        return s;
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual String Save()
    {
       String s = "";
       //attach id to s
       return s; 
     }
}
```

calling `userInstance.Save()` now would return you a string with all variables, including the id of the baseclass. (This becomes handy if you have a complex tree, where each class just should be responsible for it's own attributes.)

In practice you would not build a string, but maybe a XML-Element or a Prepared Statement ready to run with the database.

Comment: sorry If I miss something but where is user as input? and how do I create logic which I dont know which type of class I am working on. could you fill inside Save to make me understand better.

Comment: @Mert you don't need user as input. it will inherit the method as any other mehtod. You can always find out which concrete class you are working with (`if (this is User)`)And the concrete Save-Implementation depends on how you are saving.

Comment: It worked but I lost all generic functionality, I ll investigate If this has any harm of my general solution. thank you

Comment: I would like to hear from you a comment about Marc's solution. It seems you guys more experianced on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the CREATE class to:

```
public static class CREATE
{
    public static void New<T>(this T x)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

That is your extension method, they need to be in a static non-generic class. Like the error pointed out to you.

And you need to change the `Save` method to:

```
public void Save(T x)
{
    x.Save();
}
```

This calls the save extension method. Since the base class is generic and non-static it cannot contain extension methods.

Comment: And he should change the Save method to: `public void Save() { CREATE.New<T>(this); }`

Comment: adding this on New created error of this ; Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class AND removeing <T> from CREATE<T> cause this error ; The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)